# controlling the dimensions of elements html and css

Tags: html, css

I have a header element with 2 elements inside - an img and p elements.

I'd like the header height to be the exact height of the image it contains so that when I remove the margin and padding it "fits".

Rather than adjusting the height of the header element to be the same pixel height as the image, is there a way to "auto" do this?

I have tried height:auto but that just brings unexpected wonky results.

Here's the code:

```
<header>
  <img src="images/logosketch.jpg" alt="companylogo" />
  <div class="search">
    <p>SEARCH HERE</p>
  </div>
</header>

header { position: relative; }
.search { bottom: 0; position: absolute; right: 0; }
.search p { margin: 0; }
```

Any pointers?

Comment: are you setting the height of the image?

Comment: OK:
<header>
   <img src="images/logosketch.jpg" alt="companylogo" /> 
   <div class="search"><p>SEARCH HERE</p></div>
</header>

header {
 position: relative;
 }
.search {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.search p {
 margin: 0;
 }

Comment: no, I have not been setting the height of the image - should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following -

```
header { position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

header img {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
}
```

With this method, making the image a block element and manually setting its height, it will cause the parent block element to adjust its size. However, if any other block elements in that header have a greater height than the img element, then it will cause the header to take on that other elements height with the exception of block elements that are position absolute.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding from the container and margin from the image. Some browsers have their own styling on common elements. That's why many people use a [CSS Reset stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

However, if the `p` element gets bigger, so will the container so you will have to restrict that element in some way (make sure the text does not make it higher than the image or specify the height to be the same as the container.

Comment: I tried that thanks but no joy. I have added * {outline: solid 1px} to see element outlines and what I see is the img butted to the top of the screen, surrounded by the header element and a gap between the bottom of the img and its container. Could it be to do witht he fact that I have positioned the other element within the header - the div? I had positioned that in the bottom by using the code above? Note the containing element, the header, is position relative.

Comment: @DougFirr what happens if you remove the div completely (just for now)?

Comment: just checked it - no change :-/